# LinearLayout not aligned as i wish

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-xml, android-relativelayout

We'll start with a picture:

[image]

I want the `TextView` and the `EditText` of the Email address to be below the logo but somehow it's on top of it.

My layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial.LoginActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@color/white_1" >

    <!--  Header Starts-->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/hd_logo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imgae_view_logo_content_description"
                />

    </LinearLayout>         
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
    <!--  Header Ends -->

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_footer_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </LinearLayout>   
    <!-- Footer Ends -->

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

      <!--  Email Label -->
      <TextView 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@color/black_1"
          android:text="@string/login_page_email_text_view_text"
          />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/login_page_email_edit_text_id"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
          android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:hint="@string/login_page_email_edit_text_hint"
          android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
          />

      <!--  Password Label -->
      <TextView 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#372c24"
          android:text="@string/login_page_password_text_vuew_text"
          />

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:inputType="textPassword"
          android:hint="@string/login_page_password_edit_text_hint"
            />
      <!-- Login button -->
      <Button 
          android:id="@+id/login_page_login_button_id"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
          android:text="@string/login_page_login_button_text"
          />

      <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/login_page_go_to_sign_up_page_text_view_id"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
          android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
          android:text="@string/login_page_go_to_sign_up_page_text_view_text"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textColor="#0b84aa"
          />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Login Form Ends -->

   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What am i doing wrong? because all the `LinearLayout` orientation is set to vertical so how come some View are aligned on top of others?

Comment: @Stefano You all were right. Just because you were the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your father container is a RelativeLayout, so the children has to be positioned "in a relative way" between each other. For example: `linear_layout_footer_id` should be placed under `linear_layout_header_id` using

`android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_header_id"`

Other solution: replace your RelativeLayout with another LinearLayout with vertical orientation

Answer (score 2):

Since your parent layout is relative, you need to give the views conditions to come below. Here is the fixed xml for that using your xml.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial.LoginActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@color/white_1" >

    <!--  Header Starts-->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/hd_logo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imgae_view_logo_content_description"
                />

    </LinearLayout>         
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
    <!--  Header Ends -->

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_footer_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </LinearLayout>   
    <!-- Footer Ends -->

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"
        android:padding="10dip" >

      <!--  Email Label -->
      <TextView 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@color/black_1"
          android:text="@string/login_page_email_text_view_text"
          />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/login_page_email_edit_text_id"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
          android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:hint="@string/login_page_email_edit_text_hint"
          android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
          />

      <!--  Password Label -->
      <TextView 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#372c24"
          android:text="@string/login_page_password_text_vuew_text"
          />

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:inputType="textPassword"
          android:hint="@string/login_page_password_edit_text_hint"
            />
      <!-- Login button -->
      <Button 
          android:id="@+id/login_page_login_button_id"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
          android:text="@string/login_page_login_button_text"
          />

      <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/login_page_go_to_sign_up_page_text_view_id"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
          android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
          android:text="@string/login_page_go_to_sign_up_page_text_view_text"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textColor="#0b84aa"
          />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Login Form Ends -->

   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

As you can see, now your login form is given the condition

> android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"

So it will come below the header.

Answer (score 1):

add  `android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"` as

```
    <!-- Login Form -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >
```

Comment: You both right about the `android:layout_below`. But replacing the RelativeLayout with `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation messed things up. thanks you both.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your file as below :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial.LoginActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white_1" >

        <!--  Header Starts-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/hd_logo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imgae_view_logo_content_description"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Logo Ends -->
        <!--  Header Ends -->

        <!-- Footer Start -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_footer_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" <!-- Because relative layout arranges all its childs in layer we have to make them separate -->
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_footer_id">

            <!--  Email Label -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black_1"
                android:text="@string/login_page_email_text_view_text"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_page_email_edit_text_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/login_page_email_edit_text_hint"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                />

            <!--  Password Label -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="@string/login_page_password_text_vuew_text"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/login_page_password_edit_text_hint"
                />
            <!-- Login button -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_page_login_button_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="@string/login_page_login_button_text"
                />

            <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_page_go_to_sign_up_page_text_view_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
                android:text="@string/login_page_go_to_sign_up_page_text_view_text"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#0b84aa"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Login Form Ends -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Relative layout arranges all its layout relatively.
If you do not specify any relative attributes then all its child will be overlapping.

Hope It will help.!!

Answer (score 1):

add this code

```
android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_header_id"
```

to LinearLayout that should be below Logo

Answer (score 1):

You are arranging `LinerLayouts` in `RelativeLayouts`, so you need to make sure your `LinearLayouts` are relative to each other. Try to add attribute `android:layout_below`.